# Update database access , c#

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to update my access database in c# and i really do not why is not working.My code:

```
 public void EditAlbum (Album newAlbum)
    {
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE Album SET [Name]=@Name, [Description]=@Description, [Location]=@Location, [Date]=@Date,[CoverPhotoURL]=@Cover WHERE [ID]=@Id";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", newAlbum.Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", newAlbum.Description);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", newAlbum.Location);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", newAlbum.Date);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", newAlbum.ID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cover", newAlbum.CoverPhoto);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

My database have next field,in this order:ID,Name,Description,Location,Date,CoverPhotoURL.
I do not receive any error message but this code do nothing.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and verify the code is reached?

Comment: How do you know it does nothing? You don't get the expected results in the database? Is the query actually executed on database (can you see it using profiler)?

Comment: Have you tried putting a try/catch block around that code block to make 100% sure that the DB is not returning an error?

Comment: my database remain the same after calling this function, but if i call my add function , that work 
`command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Album([Name],[Description],[Location],[Date],[CoverPhotoURL]) VALUES(@Name,@Description,@Location,@Data,@Cover)";
            
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", newAlbum.Name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", newAlbum.Description);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", newAlbum.Location);`
            .....

Comment: So can you trace the database and see if the SQL is what you expect? I'm pretty sure that the query is invalid there.

Comment: this topic can be close,i write `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` in the same order as in UPDATE and know it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order in which you add the parameters to the collection.
OleDb doesn't recognize the parameters by their name, but only by their position.
So you need to add the parameters in the exact order in which their respective placeholders appear in the query

```
public void EditAlbum (Album newAlbum)
{
    command.CommandText = @"UPDATE Album SET [Name]=@Name, 
                            [Description]=@Description, 
                            [Location]=@Location, 
                            [Date]=@Date,
                            [CoverPhotoURL]=@Cover 
                            WHERE [ID]=@Id";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", newAlbum.Name);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", newAlbum.Description);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", newAlbum.Location);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", newAlbum.Date);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cover", newAlbum.CoverPhoto);
    // Moved after the Cover parameter
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", newAlbum.ID);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Wow i had no clue about it needing to be in order. I thought that Parameters used a form of `String.Replace` thank you, you might have saved me from a future bug. :)

Comment: This is a peculiarity of OleDb, if you use the SqlClient or MySql provider you could add the parameters out of order without problem. But the parameters values are never replaced using a form of string concatenation. This would defeat their biggest benefits (No Sql Injection and no parsing problems) They are passed to the db engine for proper processing

Comment: Also, OleDb use the ? (a question mark) for its parameter placeholders. But Access accepts also the @name form probably for compatibility with its big cousin Sql Server